# Why is my "if condition" corrupting my code?

Tags: jquery, function, if-statement

I have a function that sets a variable to a word from an array:

```
function PlacesToVisitSelector(var1) {
    if ( (var1 == 'TEST')){
        var PlacesToVisit =['kilopascal','psi','Torr'];
        var PlacesToVisitRandom= PlacesToVisit[Math.floor(Math.random() * PlacesToVisit.length)];
        return PlacesToVisitRandom;
    }

}

var PlacesToVisit = PlacesToVisitSelector("TEST");
$('.PlacesToVisit').html(PlacesToVisit);
```

And another function that sets a second variable to a word from the same array that's different from the original word:

```
function PlacesToVisit2Selector(var1) {
    var PlacesToVisit2 =['kilopascal','psi','Torr'];
    var PlacesToVisit2Random= PlacesToVisit2[Math.floor(Math.random() * PlacesToVisit2.length)];
    return (PlacesToVisit2Random !== PlacesToVisit) ? PlacesToVisit2Random: PlacesToVisit2Selector();
}

var PlacesToVisit2 = PlacesToVisit2Selector("TEST");
$('.PlacesToVisit2').html(PlacesToVisit2);
```

This works, but if I add the same "if" condition to the second function, it stops working sometimes:

```
function PlacesToVisit2Selector(var1) {
    if ( (var1 == 'TEST')){ 
        var PlacesToVisit2 =['kilopascal','psi','Torr'];
        var PlacesToVisit2Random= PlacesToVisit2[Math.floor(Math.random() * PlacesToVisit2.length)];
        return (PlacesToVisit2Random !== PlacesToVisit) ? PlacesToVisit2Random: PlacesToVisit2Selector();
    }
}

var PlacesToVisit2 = PlacesToVisit2Selector("TEST");
$('.PlacesToVisit2').html(PlacesToVisit2);
```

I am so confused, as I've used these functions dozens of times before and have never had any trouble. What am I missing?!

JSFiddle showing that the functions only work occasionally with the if condition in the second function: http://jsfiddle.net/1z7fqL0a/

Comment: can you add `$('.PlacesToVisit2').html(PlacesToVisit2);` in your function `PlacesToVisit2Selector` rather than outside?

Comment: I could I guess, but I don't think that gets to the core of what's going wrong. I'm so perplexed as to why the "if" condition is corrupting the code...sometimes. I should have left that part out because that's irrelevant to the function (just replaces a space with the generated variable.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this line

```
 return (PlacesToVisit2Random !== PlacesToVisit) ? PlacesToVisit2Random: PlacesToVisit2Selector();
```

Just convert it to

```
return (PlacesToVisit2Random !== PlacesToVisit) ? PlacesToVisit2Random: PlacesToVisit2Selector("TEST");
```

You need to pass `"TEST"` as an argument in order for your function to work correctly in case `PlacesToVisit2Random` and `PlacesToVisit` are same.

Comment: THANK YOU! I knew I was missing something incredibly dumb. Much appreciated for your KIND response.